# Writing down $x$ and $y$ as functions of $u$ and $v$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I need to write down $x$ and $y$ as functions of $u$ and $v$. System looks like this:

$$u=x\cdot e^y$$
$$v=y \cdot e^x$$

Does anybody know what can be done? Whatever I try I get stuck.

EDIT:

So this is the whole
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYWD4.png).

Usually, to find when Jacobian is 0, I need to find derivatives of $x$ and $y$ wrt $u$ and $v$. Apparently, that is not possible, but I don't know any other way, because we weren't taught that.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "$x$ and $y$ as functions of $u$ and $v$". It is not possible in closed form, so what else do you have in mind? In principle: $y=v\cdot e^{-x}$, substitute in the first equation, that defines $x$ *implicitly* as a function of $u$ and $v$; but you can't solve in closed form. Or was the problem different - perhaps compute the derivatives at some specific points, etc.? Google "XY problem" to understand what I mean. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I need to find partial derivatives of x and y with regarding to u and v for Jacobian. To do that, I need to write x and y as functions of u and v.

Comment: $\nu = y e^{u e^{-y}}$ is non-monotonic in $y$ for some values of $u$. Therefore, there is no inverse function.

Comment: No, you don't - that's exactly what I meant by "XY Problem." That's the whole point: you are able to find those derivatives **without** writing $x$ and $y$ as functions of $u$ and $v$. You are probably studying **implicit** differentiation in class, don't try to do it by **explicitly** solving for $x$ and $y$!

Answer (score 0):

$y \exp(u e^{-y}) = v$.  AFAIK there is no "closed-form" solution for $y$.  You can have series solutions, e.g.

$$ y = e^{-u} v + u e^{-2u} v^2 + \frac{3 u^2 - u}{2} e^{-3 u} v^3 + \frac{16 u^3 - 12 u^2 + u}{6} e^{-4u} v^4 + \ldots $$

Comment: Obviously that *wasn't* the OP's homework problem though. He is trying to do implicit differentiation by solving the equations explicitly so he can differentiate. Just the opposite of the "implicit differentiation" concept.